# Input type 'Number' not recognized by 1password in extension both Edge & chrome

Tags: 1password

I have some input types (Number) & but the 1password doesn't recognizes the `<input type="number">`.

But the input type number is working
[image]

Sample code:

```
 <td class="ADTXTFFForm2" colspan="19">
<div class="">
<input type="number" maxlength="255" name="V1$V2$V4$gbxMain$ctl11$F" ft="VC" spellcheck="false" data-ms-editor="true" class="">
</div>
</td>
```

Could you please help us to 1password recognizes the input type numer.

Thanks

Comment: Make a feature request https://1password.community/categories/general-lounge